# array file input generates warning for mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I have written this code in my config file (included everywhere) to avoid sql injection

```
$_POST = array_map("mysql_escape",$_POST);
```

and here is the function definition

```
function mysql_escape($input)
{
    global $conn;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$input);
}
```

the problem is when I add this input to my form,

```
<input id="photoUpload" type="file" name="TourPhoto[]" value='1' multiple accept="image/*">
```

and submit the form, I see this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\functions.php on line 6

Although the script works, files are uploaded successfully

If I change "TourPhoto[]" to "TourPhoto", the warning disappears; but I need to input multiple files and I'd like to know where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Javad you have answer below. check it. if worked then mark and up-vote it as an answer. thanks

Comment: Since you said that your code worked, i am deleting my stuff. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code

```
function mysql_escape($input)
{
    global $conn;
    if(is_array($input))
        return array_map("mysql_escape",$input);
    else
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$input);
}
```

it seems working